# How do I disable audio pause in Android 5.0 when receiving notifications?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications

My device is running Android 5.0 and one annoying thing about it is that if I'm listening to music and get a notification, my music will pause just to play my notification sound. Is there a way I could disable the pausing of audio when receiving a notification?  I have root access, which should help, but I don't know where to start or how to start.

Comment: Here we are, 2019, and the problem still persists even in the latest Android releases. An app was created for this purpose called Don't Pause, which worked great, but then I got a new phone, and discovered that app is no longer in the play store. And switching to another music player is out of the question, because I use YouTube and I pay for Plex to stream my own media from home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to switch to another audio player than whatever you're currently using, you can achieve this with [PowerAmp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer). It has a menu for audio focus, which has settings for pausing or not when a notification is received, and whether to pause or not when there's an incoming call.

[image]

The one I linked to is the trial version. The pro version costs roughly $5.

I'm not directly affiliated with MaxMP or PowerAmp, but I am betatesting the upcoming version.

Comment: Awesome suggestion. The only thing is, I use SoundCloud quite often. I can try PowerAmp for local music, but does this also disable pausing for notification/text sounds?

Comment: @MikeKuplevatsky The _Short Audio Focus Change_ setting does that. When enabled, it pauses for notifications. If _Duck Volume_ is also enabled, it lowers the volume instead of pausing. If _Short Audio Focus Change_ is disabled, it doesn't pause for notifications. I just tried it with wired earphones, and with the built-in speaker, by sending texts to myself.

Comment: 2021 & I'm on Galaxy S10+ PowerAmp DOES NOT FIX THIS. It briefly pauses when I click "like" on Facebook FFS. Paid version of PowerAmp